# How to pass a variable to subprocess.Popen.stdin.write() in Python

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, popen

I am using Popen from subprocess library and wish to pass a variable to popen.stdin.write for executing a bat file. I wish to execute my bat file by

`C:\Users\7zx3we\test.bat chinni`

Mycode

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

p = Popen('cmd.exe ', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
name = 'chinni'
p.stdin.write('C:\Users\7zx3we\test.bat ' + name + '\n')
```

But this is giving me a syntax error and failing to run. What can I try to resolve that?

Comment: Best to include (verbatim) any errors you get with your question but you'd probably need to use raw strings, e.g., `r'C:\Users\7zx3we\test.bat '` since the `'\t'` is a tab character.

Comment: Additionally (next to @JustinEzequiel 's comment), you're only importing `Popen`, but you'll also need to import `PIPE` from `subprocess`

Comment: I'm importing `PIPE` too. made the edit

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to define the encoding if you want to open `stdin` in text mode. You can do this by specifying the `encoding` parameter:

```
Popen('cmd.exe`, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf8')
```

2. You need to escape the backslashes in the path, since otherwise they will be evaluated to a wrong value, e.g., `\U` starts a [Unicode escape sequence](https://dencode.com/en/string/unicode-escape) and `\t` is the tab character:

```
p.stdin.write('C:\\Users\\7zx3we\\test.bat ' + name)
```